# Flex-How do I apply effects in <s:NavigatorContent>?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, effects

I'm trying to apply effects on `<s:NavigatorContent>`.
Like:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:WipeUp id="myWU" duration="300"/>
    <mx:WipeDown id="myWD" duration="300"/>
    <mx:WipeRight id="myWR" duration="300"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:HGroup gap="0">
<s:ButtonBar dataProvider="{viewStack}" >
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
</s:ButtonBar>
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack">

    <!-- Following wiil work
    <mx:Canvas id="View1" label="View1" showEffect="{myWD}" hideEffect="{myWU}">
        <views:View1 />
    </mx:Canvas>

    <mx:Canvas id="View2" label="View2" showEffect="{myWD}" hideEffect="{myWU}">
        <views:View2 />
    </mx:Canvas>-->

    <s:NavigatorContent label="View1" showEffect="{myWD}" hideEffect="{myWU}">
        <views:View1 />
    </s:NavigatorContent >

    <s:NavigatorContent label="View2" showEffect="{myWD}" hideEffect="{myWU}">
        <views:View2 />
    </s:NavigatorContent >

</mx:ViewStack>
</s:HGroup>
```

But it did't worked.
May be there is an issue with event propagation but how do I make it worked?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should not use mx effects on spark containers.

Why don't you try using the Wipe Spark effect.

Good luck with that!

Gabriel.-

Answer (score 0):

Effect triggers like hideEffect/showEffect are not officially supported in spark in the current release. You can track the progress of this feature here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-19743

Comment: In the [Help docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSb96f4baaef289fcf-2107ed10123b8e266e7-8000.html), I see comment: Events do not propagate down to children, but up to parents. If you want to do something to a child based on a container event, handle it in the container's event handler.